# CSS3 Button Background and Text color animations Order

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions

Trying to order animation timing for background and text change on hover. First animation background color to blue and changing text color after background reaching text

**Issue:**

Both background and text animations are starting at same time instead of background first and then text color

Reference code :

```css
    div {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 20px;
        background: grey;
    }

    a {
        line-height: 19px;
        padding: 15px 25px 16px;
        background: white;
        border: none;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none!important;
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        font-size: 14px!important;
        width: 220px;
    }

    a:hover,
    a:hover span {
        background-position: 0 100%;
    }


    .button {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, blue 50%, #fff 0);
        background-position: 100% 100%;
        background-size: 200% 100%;
        color: #242424!important;
        transition: all 10s ease;
    }

    .button span {
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
        background-clip: text;
        background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #fff, #fff 50%, #242424 0);
        background-position: 100%;
        background-size: 200% 100%;
        position: relative;
        text-decoration: none;
        transition: all 5s ease;
    }
```

```html
    <div>
        <a class="button">
            <span>Testing</span>
        </a>
    <div>
```

Tried using transition-delay but it has no effect

Codepen URL - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/mdRBZbd

From online found below solution but it works with creating with two elements but playing around to use only one element and CSS

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.btn {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #222;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #222;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: monospace;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}
.btn [class^=btn__text] {
  font-size: 24px;
}
.btn .btn__text-dynamic,
.btn .btn__text-dynamic-inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: all ease 10s;
}
.btn .btn__text-dynamic {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #222;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.btn:hover .btn__text-dynamic {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
.btn:hover .btn__text-dynamic-inner {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn--animation-from-right">
  <span class="btn__text-static">Cover left</span>
  <div class="btn__text-dynamic">
    <span class="btn__text-dynamic-inner">Cover left</span>
  </div>
</button>
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/zYNpgpQ

Answer (score 0):

Using `transition-delay` should solve the problem:

```css
.button span {
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
        background-clip: text;
        background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #fff, #fff 50%, #242424 0);
        background-position: 100%;
        background-size: 200% 100%;
        position: relative;
        text-decoration: none;
        transition: all 10s ease;


        transition-delay: 10s;
    }
```

Comment: thanks @Moamen for the answer, using transition-delay is delaying color change and taking effect only after complete background change ...instead of text color change with backgroound color change smoothly..posted one sample working solution found from online but it uses two elements to achieve it